# Get Data in a particular Format from serializers in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

My Models:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=25)


class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Student_subject_mapping(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm trying to get all `Student_subject_mapping` data in the database in a format given below:

```
{
"results": [{
    "id": 1,        ----------------> student id
    "email": "student_1@gmail.com",------------> student email
    "subjects": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "subject_1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "subject_2"
        },
        ...
    ]
},
```

What will be the query to get the data in the following manner?
How can I achieve data in the above format?

Answer (score 0):

change the subject model to

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subjects')
```

and StudentSerializer to

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'subjects')
        depth = 1
```

or you get a result like this :

```
result = {
    "subject": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "subject_1"
    },
    "student": {
        "id": 2,
        "email": "subject_2"
    }
}
```

by editing the **Student_Mapping_Serializers** to

```
class Student_Mapping_Serializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
       model = Student_subject_mapping
       fields = "__all__"
       depth = 1
```

hope it helps .

## edited

```
class Student_Mapping_Serializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subject = SubjectSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
       model = Student_subject_mapping
       fields = ("student", "subject")
       depth = 1
```

Comment: Is it possible without changing the model ?

Comment: you can get result like this without changing models, result = {
    "subject": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "subject_1"
    },
    "student": {
        "id": 2,
        "email": "subject_2"
    }
}

Comment: I only want the email of a student not all data in an object, How can it be achieved ?

Comment: for that, you need to modify the Student_subject_mapping model,
here  student and subject are foreign keys. if you change subject to manytomany field, you can add multiple, subjects to the Student_subject_mapping model, and can get the desired output

Comment: so I have changed my subject to many to many field , now how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Something worth noting I would recommend naming your classes in [**use the CapWords convention**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) e.g `StudentSubjectMapping` following **PEP8** style guide.

We'll refactor our class as shown below. To answer your question we can have a [**property method**](https://djangocentral.com/property-decorator-explained/) for student email at `StudentSubjectMapping` model. What the **@property** decorator does, is declare that it can be accessed like it's a regular property of the class.

Then since the student can have many subjects we will have to do some slight modification to the `StudentSubjectMapping` class model. We will refactor

**Refactor:**

`subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

**To**

`subjects = models.ManyToMany(Subject)`

the `subjects` as [**ManyToMany**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

And have the following implementation:

```
class StudentSubjectMapping(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subjects = models.ManyToMany(Subject)

    @property
    def email(self):
      return self.student.email
```

##### Update your serializers as follows:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class SubjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
       model = Subject
       fields = '__all__'
    

class StudentMappingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField() # use Serializer field handle converting between primitive values and internal datatypes. 
    subjects = SubjectSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
       model = StudentSubjectMapping
       """
        id -> student mapping id (integer)
        student -> FK which is an (integer)
        email -> (string)
        subjects: -> (list of subjects)
       """
       fields = ['id',"student","email","subjects"]
```

##### OutPut JSON

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "student": 2,
 "email": "student@example.edu",
 "subjects":[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Algebra"
 },
      {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Physics"
 }
]

}
```